# PHP MySQL update statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have searched online for possible reasons of why a MYSQL update statement won't work but none of the solutions work on my case. What could be wrong in these lines of code?

```
     public function forgotPassword($email, $newpassword, $salt){
     $result = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"UPDATE users SET user_password = '$newpassword',salt = '$salt'
                      WHERE email = '$email'");
```

I have tried,

```
"UPDATE 'users' SET 'user_password' = '$newpassword','salt' = '$salt'
                      WHERE 'email' = '$email'"
```

I have also tried,

```
"UPDATE 'DBNAME'.'users' SET 'user_password' = '$newpassword','salt' = '$salt'
                      WHERE 'users'.'email' = '$email'"
```

The `forgotPassword` function works properly, only the UPDATE statement is not executed.

Here is the complete function

```
    public function forgotPassword($email, $newpassword, $salt){
$result = mysqli_query($this->db->con,"UPDATE `melobook_customers`.`users` SET `user_password` ='$newpassword',`salt` ='$salt'
                      WHERE `users`.`email` ='$email'");

     if ($result) {
      return true;
      }
   else
     {
     return false;
     }

     }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: You're confusing backticks with inverted commas

Comment: @Strawberry good point, but his original query should still work as it contains no mysql reserved keywords.

Comment: @izzEps no I am not getting any errors.

Comment: have you confirmed that the email address for the user you are trying to update actually exists in the database?

Comment: @IzzEps Yeah all that is sorted. When the user enters his email in forgot password field, it checks whether the user exists, then send randrom password. The random password is what i need to update in the UPDATE MySql statement

Comment: you are missing closing brace `}` for the function in the question.

Comment: please add a `or die( mysqli_error($this->db->con) )` to the end of your `mysqli_query(...)`statement to allow errors reach us.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is within your query, you used table name within single quotes which should not be used, here you can see: **'users'**. Instead of the single quotes you've to use **`users`** or you can leave that like this **users**. So your query will look something like this,

> "UPDATE `users` SET `user_password` = '$newpassword',`salt` = '$salt'
>                         WHERE `email` = '$email'"

//I have also tried,
Your second query will look something like this

> "UPDATE `DBNAME`.`users` SET `users`.`user_password` = '$newpassword',`users`.`salt` = '$salt'
>                         WHERE `users`.`email` = '$email'"

Updated Code Based on your requirement

```
<?php
        class check_update{

            private $con;

            public function __construct(){
                $this->con = mysqli_connect("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");
            }

            public function forgotPassword($email, $newpassword, $salt){
                $sql = "UPDATE `db_name`.`table_name` SET `table_name`.`password` ='$newpassword',`table_name`.`salt` = '$salt' WHERE `table_name`.`email` ='$email'";
                $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
                if ($result) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        $check_update = new check_update();
        $check_update->forgotPassword("your_email", "new_password", "salt");
?>
```

Hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Actually I've forgot to mention that you cant use single quotes anywhere in your query for table_name, database_name, column_names etc. You can use single quotes only for strings. Like below is the sample query for you.

> UPDATE  `stackoverflow_question`.`test` SET  `password` =  '$newpassword',
`salt` =  '$salt' WHERE  `email` =  '$email'

Comment: I have tried your solution, it hasnt worked. Could the problem be in the rest of the function? Check my edit

Comment: what is the value of $this->db->con property, have you seen that using var_dump($this->db->con); please check what it contains?